# Star Trek Continues: ffmeg dvdsub: overlapping subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

So I've downloaded the free fan-created [Star Trek Continues](https://www.startrekcontinues.com/) Blue-Ray ISO for [Episodes 1-3](https://www.startrekcontinues.com/STC_VOL1_BR.torrent) and I'm trying to convert the FHD 1920x1080 to SD 960x540 to be able to watch on my phone:

```
ffmpeg -canvas_size 960x540 \
-i /media/STC_VOL1_BR/BDMV/STREAM/00000.m2ts \
-map_metadata -1 \
-c:v libx264 -map 0:0 -strict -2 -r 24 -s 960x540 \
-c:a libmp3lame -map 0:1 -b:a 384K \
-metadata:s:s:0 language=EN -c:s dvdsub -map 0:2 \
/media/Videos/Star\ Trek\ Continues/S01E01\ Pilgrim\ Of\ Eternity.mkv
```

but after a few seconds of watching the converted mkv, the subtitles become:

- unreadable due to overlapping
- are slightly big (no issue)
- shifted to the right and bottom of the screen

[image: VLC Screenshot]

[Full ffmpeg output here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zcGxNG8fJT/)

*What am I doing wrong?*

<sub>**Note 1:** I've only ever dealt with `srt` subtitles and I  know that dvdsubs are images, so that's why I thought the `canvas_size` parameter might be of help, but it makes no difference.</sub>
<sub>**Note 2:** Yeah, it's not really a pure Ubuntu OS question, but over on [video.se](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27676/star-trek-continues-ffmeg-dvdsub-overlapping-subtitles) not getting *any attention, even with a bounty* so trying here if anyone does any video conversion and has run into the same situation.</sub>

Comment: In the FFmpeg terminal output is there a section with `sub2video: using 1920x1080 canvas` or does it show the altered canvas size? Full terminal output would be helpful for your question...

Comment: @andrew.46 Full ffmpeg output of the first 25 seconds of conversion [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zcGxNG8fJT/) (also added to q)

Comment: Thanks for providing the FFmpeg output! Looks like `-canvas_size` is working well enough. 2 more thoughts: 1. Try adding in the ` -fix_sub_duration` option which may correct the overwriting issue. 2. Your FFmpeg version is a little aged perhaps try with git. If no joy from either of these thoughts I will download that big file and have a go...

Comment: @andrew.46 your help so far has been better than on the video site.  I don't understand that with such a detailed question I'm only getting a one-liner that is totally not useful there...  I'm out of the country for a job interview so I'll try whenever I can.

Comment: Deja vu upvoting this Q&A :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically the *cleanest* look with these subtitles would be to:

1. Extract the subtitles
2. Turn them to text using your favourite OCR application
3. Carefully review and edit the text
4. Burn them back into the media stream in the size, colour, orientation and format of your choice

This is a large and time consuming job which [I have personally undertaken in the past](https://web.archive.org/web/20130320170316/http://www.andrews-corner.org/fist.html#subtitles) but is probably *overkill* in this case.

The *better* option is to simply add in the FFmpeg option `-fix_sub_duration` (placed *before* the input file) and this will fix the doubled up subtitles as I illustrate below, and make the subtitles easily readable:

[image]

The details of the `-fix_sub_duration` option can be found in the FFmpeg-all man pages but I have taken the liberty of quoting these details here:

> -fix_sub_duration
>
> Fix subtitles durations. For each subtitle, wait for the next packet in the same stream and adjust the duration of the
>   first to avoid overlap. This is necessary with some subtitles codecs,
>   especially DVB subtitles, because the duration in the original packet
>   is only a rough estimate and the end is actually marked by an empty
>   subtitle frame. Failing to use this option when necessary can result
>   in exaggerated durations or muxing failures due to non-monotonic
>   timestamps.
>
> Note that this option will delay the output of all data until the next
>   subtitle packet is decoded: it may increase memory consumption and
>   latency a lot.

You will note that this is the *first* of the Advanced Subtitle options, the *second* being the `-canvas_size` that you have already used...